# Getting product information from a external database

Tags: database, mysql, magento-1.9, importexport

I have been given an unfinished product from a client, and it is a mess.

This is my first time ever using Magento, but I have used other CMS's. So please bare with me as I am a "newbie". I do have experience with PHP, MYSQL, and a few others.

Let me give a few specifics, so I can give you a better idea on what I am trying to accomplish.

I am using Magento 1.9

My client owns a bookstore, and they get almost 100 new books each week (all different IBSN's). As it sits right now they are going through a lengthy process to export and import CSV files to get this information on Magento.

So leading into my question, can we import/stream this info from an external database?  We have access to a database that has all of the products information (descriptions, author info, publication info, etc) and all we need to do is link the 2 together.

Is this possible? Or a similar way that could help the ease of this process?

Thank you in advanced for the help.

Comment: You should write a custom module and add your external DB specifications to that module.

Comment: try Magmi its open source, direct sql queries, well documented, lighting fast.

Answer (score 1):

There are many third party extensions that can be modified to import products, you could have the file copied to your Magento var folder, then run a cron to import the products on a daily basis.

I would NOT try to import products directly to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could always looking into building your own import, not directly into the database and buy using something that uses the existing import process but simply makes it easier to customize.

My suggestion would be to use [Avs_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) which will allow you to build arrays with all the product, category and even customer information and then import all the data into Magento.

If you have some php experience this would be a good way of looking into it. There is also a good overview of a few other import modules http://www.integer-net.com/2014/05/27/product-import-with-magento/ which might be some good reading for you.